# Is there extension for viewing navigation history in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Is there extension, that will remember all visited files, and show it? Visited positions also would be great.

For example:

1. I opened MyFile1.cs. Extension remembered this.
2. I navigated to function HelloThere() in this file, extension remebered.
3. I navigated to line in function Foo() in this file, extnsion remebered.
4. I opened file MyFile2.cs...

Then, I open some panel, and all visited files and positions are shown like history in the browser:

```
15:25 MyFile2.cs
15:24 MyFile1.cs:HelloThere()
15:23 MyFile1.cs:Foo()
15:23 MyFile1.cs
```

I [tried](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=navigation%20history&f%5B0%5D.Value=navigation%20history&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B1%5D.Value=14.0&f%5B1%5D.Type=VisualStudioVersion&f%5B1%5D.Text=Visual%20Studio%202015&f%5B2%5D.Value=Productivity&f%5B2%5D.Type=Tag&ac=4) to find, nothing found. There is Ctrl+"-" combination to go back, but it is too tiny. I need something like this, but more powerfull.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the little down arrow by the back button, the history that it'll go through is listed:

[image: Picture of back button]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this can help you, but, there is a way for your Scroll Bar shows all of the changes of files.

To enable (using VS 2015 comunity):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but not enough. I working in big project, and often I navigate there and there, investigating code execution path. So, I got thousands tabs opened, and feel myself lost in this heap of documents. There is Ctrl + "-" combination to go back, but it is too tiny. I need smth like this, but more powerfull.